# How many ways can you select 10 pieces of fruit with 4 different types and 5 each?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given 5 apples, 5 oranges, 5 bananas, and 5 pears, how many ways can you select 10 total fruits, having a minimum of 2 oranges and 1 apple?
So far I have narrowed it down to having 4 apples left, 2 oranges, and 5 of the remaining ones

Comment: What do you mean by "have narrowed it down to... "? Could you show us what you have done?

Comment: If you were allowed to write a computer program to solve it, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

We have to count the integer solutions of $a+o+b+p=7$, given the constraints
$$a\in[0..4],\quad o\in[0..3],\quad  b,p\in[0..5]\ .$$ Let $x:=a+o$. Then $(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$ is the list of possible values of $x$, and the list $(1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1)$ gives the numbers of corresponding admissible pairs $(a,o)$. Let $y:=b+p=7-x$ with value list $(7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)$. It is easily checked that the  numbers of corresponding admissible pairs $(b,p)$ are given by the list $(4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1)$.

The total nmber of admissible selections therefore is
$$1\cdot4+2\cdot5+3\cdot6+4\cdot5+4\cdot4+3\cdot3+2\cdot2+1\cdot1=82\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's say total number of oranges is $(a+2)$, total number of apples is $(b+1)$, total number of bananas is $c$ and total number of pears is $d$.

We know that
$$a+b+c+d=7$$

So for $(a+2)$ oranges and $(b+1)$ apples, the number of ways to arrange the bananas and pears is
$$\sum_{c=0}^{7-a-b} \left( \frac{{5 \choose c}}{c!} \cdot \frac{{5 \choose {7-a-b-c}}}{(7-a-b-c)!} \right)$$

Hence, for $(a+2)$ oranges, the total number of ways to arrange the rest of the fruits is
$$ \sum_{b=0}^{7-a} \left( \frac{{5 \choose {b+1}}}{(b+1)!} \cdot \sum_{c=0}^{7-a-b} \left( \frac{{5 \choose c}}{c!} \cdot \frac{{5 \choose {7-a-b-c}}}{(7-a-b-c)!} \right) \right)$$

Thus, the grand total number of ways is

$$ \sum_{a=0}^{7} \left(  \frac{{5 \choose {a+2}}}{(a+2)!} \cdot \sum_{b=0}^{7-a} \left( \frac{{5 \choose {b+1}}}{(b+1)!} \cdot \sum_{c=0}^{7-a-b} \left( \frac{{5 \choose c}}{c!} \cdot \frac{{5 \choose {7-a-b-c}}}{(7-a-b-c)!} \right) \right) \right)$$